# Git - managing multiple branches

Tags: git, heroku, github

I have an app deployed on heroku. I've connected my GitHub account to heroku so if I push anything to the `master` branch it is automatically
deployed on heroku and made available to the customer.

To improve this process I've created a `development` branch where I push all my code while I'm developing and testing out my code. Once that code is ready I want to push it to the `master` branch to be deployed on heroku.

**What I did:**

*Create Branch*

```
git branch development
```

*Access Development Branch*

```
git checkout development
```

*Pushed Changes to Development Branch*

```
git add .
git commit -am "did something"
git push -u origin development
```

All of this worked.

**My Issue:**

I can't figure out the correct process of and how to do the following, from the console:

1. Pushes changes from `development` to `master` branch so say they are equal
2. Do I need to create a new branch every time I am developing or can I keep reusing the `development` branch?

Comment: There are many workflows you can use so unfortunately I'm going to vote to close your question as primarily opinion-based. However, I would consider the development branch as "ready to release, just not yet". From the development branch I would take out feature-branches for new things and only merge them into development when you feel they're ready to release, *even if you don't release from development to master yet*. This way you have the luxury of releasing everything on development when its time, without having to worry about releasing unfinished/untested changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. Updating the `master` branch from the `development` branch, and
2. deciding on the general workflow.

### Updating `master` branch

The easiest way to keep your master in sync with the development branch is to locally merge in the development branch and then push the updated master to your GitHub repository:

```
git checkout master
git merge development
git push origin master
```

If there was no work done on the master branch directly (as you allude to in your question) the merge should be [fast-forward](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/git-fast-forwards-and-branch-management-329977726.html).

You can then check out the development branch again and continue working:

```
git checkout development
```

All in all, the graph of this procedure would follow something like this:

```
-- A -- B -- C          merge       -- A -- B -- C
   |         |         ------->                  |
 master   development                         master, development
```

Now, onto the more trickier part:

### Choosing your workflow

There are countless ways of managing your branches, and there is no canonical one-for-all solution that works for projects of all scales and complexities. That is the power of such a flexible system such as git, but at the same time a small drawback, because *which system should you choose*?

I would recommend to look at some articles and blog posts on [git workflows](https://www.google.com/search?q=git%20workflows) and then choose one that suits you. If the boundary conditions of your project change, you can always reassess and change the git workflow for that project as you see fit.

> Do I need to create a new branch every time I am developing or can I keep reusing the development branch?

With the procedure outlined above, you can continue working on your development branch without any extra steps.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take a time to watch some git workflow video, you should create a branch for every new functionality, in a real project a branch should not stay open for more than 2 days to avoid merge problem.

Use `git merge` to import changes from branch to master https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Comment: ... but if hotfixes or other commit appear in `master`, rebase the `development` branch on top of it

Answer (score 0):

1. You can either merge your development branch into master or rebase master on your development branch. Some people think that one solution is better that the other, but that's up to you. [Here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing) is good explanations about the differences.
2. This question is really about the workflow. The only rule is that all the people who are working on that git repo agree about what they will do. So If you are alone you can do as you want. But once again some people will tell that you *must* create new branches for each feature, and opnce again that's up to you.
3. I would advise you to use some GUI client for Git. There are among others [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) or [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/). I'm currently using GitKraken, and it allow to [handle a git flow](https://support.gitkraken.com/repositories/git-flow) pretty easily.